# Empty Stack Exception for Infix Expression Solver

Tags: java, exception, stack, infix-notation

So this program is suppose to take a syntactically correct infix expression that contain integer operands and the four arithmetic operators (+ - * /) from a GUI and display the results. Im having trouble when an expression is entered in parentheses.

For example, this expression

```
5+3-2
```

will return 6, but the same expression in parenthesis

```
(5+3-2)
```

returns a empty stack exception.

I've tried stepping through this as carefully as i could but i'm to know avail. The compiler is pointing the error within the third while loop which would indicate to my best guess that the stack valueStack doesn't have two values at the time but i can't seem to figure out why. Can anybody help me figure out what i'm doing wrong?

```
   public String infix(String expression)
   {
      expression=expression.replaceAll("[\t\n ]", "");
      String operator = "*/+-";
      int value1, value2;
      char ch;
      StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(expression, operator, true); 
      Stack<Integer> valueStack = new Stack<Integer>();
      Stack<Character> operatorStack = new Stack<Character>();

      while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
      {
         String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
         if(isInteger(token) == true)
            valueStack.push(Integer.parseInt(token));
         else if(token.charAt(0) == '(')
            operatorStack.push(token.charAt(0));
         else if(token.charAt(0) == ')')
            while(operatorStack.peek() != '(')
            {
               value1 = valueStack.pop();
               value2 = valueStack.pop();
               valueStack.push(solver(value1, value2, operatorStack.pop()));
               operatorStack.pop();
            }
         else if(token.charAt(0) == '+' || token.charAt(0) == '-' || token.charAt(0) == '*' || token.charAt(0) == '/')
         {
            while(!operatorStack.isEmpty() && precedence(token.charAt(0)) <= precedence(operatorStack.peek()))
            {
               value1 = valueStack.pop(); 
               value2 = valueStack.pop(); //empty stack error starts here
               valueStack.push(solver(value1, value2, operatorStack.pop()));
            }
            operatorStack.push(token.charAt(0));
         }
      }
      while(!operatorStack.isEmpty())
      {
         value1 = valueStack.pop();
         value2 = valueStack.pop();
         ch = operatorStack.pop();
         valueStack.push(solver(value1, value2, ch));
      }


      String result = Integer.toString(valueStack.pop());
      return result;     
   }  //End of infix

   public static boolean isInteger(String s)
   {
      try
      { 
         Integer.parseInt(s);
      } 
      catch(NumberFormatException e)
      {
         return false; 
      } 
      catch(NullPointerException e) 
      {
         return false;
      }
      return true;
   } // end of isInteger

   public int solver( int value1, int value2, char operator)
   {
      try
      {
         if(operator == '*')
            return value2 * value1;
         else if(operator == '/')
            return value2 / value1;
         else if(operator == '+')
            return value2 + value1;
         else if(operator == '-')
            return value2 - value1;
         else
            return 0;
      }
      catch(ArithmeticException e )
      {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Division by Zero");
      }
      return 0;
   } // end of solver

   public int precedence(char op)
   {
      if(op == '+' || op == '-')
         return 1;
      else if(op == '*' || op == '/')
         return 2;
      else
         return 0;
   }   // end of precedence
```

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is far too much code here.  In order to make it clear exactly where your problem is, please remove any code that is not directly causing your problem, and if you can reduce it to ten lines or less, I will consider retracting the downvote.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I have only fixed the bug for the crash on surrounding an expression with brackets. I haven't tested for other stuff, sorry.

There were a few issues (which I have included comments for in the debugged code) But essentially you are assuming you have 2 values on a stack at one point, when really you only have one. This is because the first number you were putting on was never getting put on, since it had a "(" attached to it. The first token was "(5" rather than "(", so it never got to the 5, anyway here is the code haha

```
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Calc {

    public String infix(String expression)
    {
        expression=expression.replaceAll("[\t\n ]", "");
        String operator = "(*/+-)"; // I added (,) see line 20 for why ...
        int value1, value2;
        char ch;
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(expression, operator, true); 
        Stack<Integer> valueStack = new Stack<Integer>();
        Stack<Character> operatorStack = new Stack<Character>();

        while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
            // the token here was "(5" when really it should be 5, therefore 5 doesn't get put on the value stack, which has consequences
            // see line 37 ...
            if(isInteger(token) == true)
                valueStack.push(Integer.parseInt(token));
            else if(token.charAt(0) == '(')
                operatorStack.push(token.charAt(0));
            else if(token.charAt(0) == ')')
                while(operatorStack.peek() != '(') // also need to check if the stack is empty here ...
                {
                    value1 = valueStack.pop();
                    value2 = valueStack.pop();
                    valueStack.push(solver(value1, value2, operatorStack.pop()));
                    operatorStack.pop();
                    // also need to check if the stack is empty here ...
                    if (operatorStack.isEmpty())
                        break;
                }
            else if(token.charAt(0) == '+' || token.charAt(0) == '-' || token.charAt(0) == '*' || token.charAt(0) == '/')
            {
                while(!operatorStack.isEmpty() && precedence(token.charAt(0)) <= precedence(operatorStack.peek()))
                {   // the bug happens because there is only one value [3] on the valueStack, and here you assume there are 2 (should be 3,5)
                    value1 = valueStack.pop(); 
                    value2 = valueStack.pop(); //empty stack error starts here
                    valueStack.push(solver(value1, value2, operatorStack.pop()));
                }
                operatorStack.push(token.charAt(0));
            }
        }
        while(!operatorStack.isEmpty())
        {
            value1 = valueStack.pop();
            value2 = valueStack.pop();
            ch = operatorStack.pop();
            valueStack.push(solver(value1, value2, ch));
        }


        String result = Integer.toString(valueStack.pop());
        return result;     
    }  //End of infix

    public static boolean isInteger(String s)
    {
        try
        { 
            Integer.parseInt(s);
        } 
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            return false; 
        } 
        catch(NullPointerException e) 
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } // end of isInteger

    public int solver( int value1, int value2, char operator)
    {
        try
        {
            if(operator == '*')
                return value2 * value1;
            else if(operator == '/')
                return value2 / value1;
            else if(operator == '+')
                return value2 + value1;
            else if(operator == '-')
                return value2 - value1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
        catch(ArithmeticException e )
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Division by Zero");
        }
        return 0;
    } // end of solver

    public int precedence(char op)
    {
        if(op == '+' || op == '-')
            return 1;
        else if(op == '*' || op == '/')
            return 2;
        else
            return 0;
    }   // end of precedence


    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Calc c = new Calc();

        System.out.println(c.infix("(5+2-1)")); // heyy it works now :)
    }

}
```

Just a quick edit, the above code will still throw an exception for expressions like this (5+(3+2)) ie nested brackets, so I added a quick (maybe not very pretty) fix for this too:

```
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Calc {

    public String infix(String expression)
    {
        expression=expression.replaceAll("[\t\n ]", "");
        String operator = "(*/+-)"; // I added (,) see line 20 for why ...
        int value1, value2;
        char ch;
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(expression, operator, true); 
        Stack<Integer> valueStack = new Stack<Integer>();
        Stack<Character> operatorStack = new Stack<Character>();

        // added this in:
        boolean stopParsingBrackets = false;

        while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
            // the token here was "(5" when really it should be 5, therefore 5 doesn't get put on the value stack, which has consequences
            // see line 37 ...
            if(isInteger(token) == true)
                valueStack.push(Integer.parseInt(token));
            else if(token.charAt(0) == '(' && stopParsingBrackets)
                operatorStack.push(token.charAt(0));
            else if(token.charAt(0) == ')' && stopParsingBrackets)
                while(operatorStack.peek() != '(') // also need to check if the stack is empty here ...
                {
                    value1 = valueStack.pop();
                    value2 = valueStack.pop();
                    valueStack.push(solver(value1, value2, operatorStack.pop()));
                    operatorStack.pop();
                    // also need to check if the stack is empty here ...
                    if (operatorStack.isEmpty()) {
                        stopParsingBrackets = true;
                    }
                }
            else if(token.charAt(0) == '+' || token.charAt(0) == '-' || token.charAt(0) == '*' || token.charAt(0) == '/')
            {
                while(!operatorStack.isEmpty() && precedence(token.charAt(0)) <= precedence(operatorStack.peek()))
                {   // the bug happens because there is only one value [3] on the valueStack, and here you assume there are 2 (should be 3,5)
                    value1 = valueStack.pop(); 
                    value2 = valueStack.pop(); //empty stack error starts here
                    valueStack.push(solver(value1, value2, operatorStack.pop()));
                }
                operatorStack.push(token.charAt(0));
            }
        }
        while(!operatorStack.isEmpty())
        {
            value1 = valueStack.pop();
            value2 = valueStack.pop();
            ch = operatorStack.pop();
            valueStack.push(solver(value1, value2, ch));
        }


        String result = Integer.toString(valueStack.pop());
        return result;     
    }  //End of infix

    public static boolean isInteger(String s)
    {
        try
        { 
            Integer.parseInt(s);
        } 
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            return false; 
        } 
        catch(NullPointerException e) 
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } // end of isInteger

    public int solver( int value1, int value2, char operator)
    {
        try
        {
            if(operator == '*')
                return value2 * value1;
            else if(operator == '/')
                return value2 / value1;
            else if(operator == '+')
                return value2 + value1;
            else if(operator == '-')
                return value2 - value1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
        catch(ArithmeticException e )
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Division by Zero");
        }
        return 0;
    } // end of solver

    public int precedence(char op)
    {
        if(op == '+' || op == '-')
            return 1;
        else if(op == '*' || op == '/')
            return 2;
        else
            return 0;
    }   // end of precedence


    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Calc c = new Calc();

        System.out.println(c.infix("(5+(2-1+2))")); // heyy it works now :)
    }

}
```